# How to know if a Galaxy Note is a real one?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note

I'm in Thailand now and I've seen a Galaxy Note device that seems to be a real Galaxy Note phone, but it has an extremely low cost (about 100 USD). I'd like to confirm that the phone is real, how do I prove it? I had the chance to play with the operating system and it is like my Galaxy S, but with a larger screen. I cannot "open" or connect to laptop, but I can play with it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Grab MAC address of Wi-Fi adapter of device. Go to `Settings` ~> `Wireless and Network` ~> `Wi-Fi Settings` and tap/press options key. Then, tap `Advanced`. Here, you can get MAC address. The method can vary based on firmware.
2. Look up this MAC address at http://www.techzoom.net/tools/check-mac.en or http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/ . If device isn't legitimate, you can detect here.

Comment: This isn't a fail-proof way. If they faked everything else what's the guarantee that they won't fake the MAC address?

Comment: @Richard Getting MAC of unit from manufacturer's range isn't easy. So, they don't generally care.

Comment: But yes, its still not a super solid way...

Comment: Generally these knock-offs don't have unique MAC addresses. Remember they're already violating laws so getting certified isn't on their agenda.

Comment: @Richard They can spoof only first six digits. After that, they'll fail. Most of lookup tools have access to manufacturer's database. Are you getting my point?

Comment: If I get the real address of a (or several) devices than those will verify. First six digits? There must be workarounds.

Comment: @Richard To get MAC to produce thousands of units, you'll have to break seal of thousands of official unit because addressing is done randomly.

Comment: First six digits are constant for a manufacturer..

Answer (score 0):

Gadgets in Thailand are way cheaper than anywhere else but, there's a small heads-up - more than likely, it will have a CSC code for Thailand, Asia, so the updates on that would be somewhat, slower than the rest of the region zones.

Having said that, you can flash it with a different regional CSC code. So go for it, when the first Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" (P1010T with Wifi only) came out, it was on sale there in Thailand - a mate of mine was there, and got it for me - 200 euros - it was a steal, it would have been about 450euros to buy in the EU. And yes, it was genuine, the real thing! :)

Comment: Cheap? Yeah, but this cheap?  They're more than 7x the price in my country. Making the device costs more this price. If this was real I could make a fortune importing these :)

Comment: Funnily enough, my mate regrets it in not buying a few and make a few from selling it :)